# Returning error from SignalR server method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, http-status-codes

I am new to SignalR and there is a small detail I can't get my head around.

My SignalR hub include many channels and the clients can join one or many of these channels via a server method:

```
joinChannel(string channelName)
```

What I don't understand is what this method should return.

If it were a normal "RPC" method I would return a status (200 - Ok, 404 - Not found, 403 - Forbidden etc) via `IHttpActionResult`.

How do I indicate success/failure in SignalR?
What determines if the reply gets to `.done` or `.fail` in the client?

**Update**
Currently my method returns a non-zero value in case of error.

```
int joinChannel(string channelName) {
    ...
    return errorCode;
}
```

This works but it create unnecessarily complicated code in the client

```
hubProxy.server.joinChannel('channel1')
               .done(function (result) {
                         if (result != 0) {
                             // error handling
                         }
                     })
               .fail(function (error) {
                        // error handling
                     });
```

Answer (score 2):

To confirm that your action was successfully performed, you can have a client method call. So, basically it would look like this:

```
    public void ServerMethod(argumentList)
    {
       if (/* server code executed successfully */)
           Clients.Caller.onSuccess(arguments); 

       else Clients.Caller.onFailure(arguments);
    }
```

What this piece of code does is to notify the caller of the server method of a success/failure by calling a client method - method defined in JavaScript. You can also have a method executed on All clients, or only on specific users.

Since it is not an RPC mechanism, I think this is the closest thing you can do to simulate a return type in SignalR.

Hope this helps!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand your concept but it looks very complicated to use on the client side. Currently my method return the error code but it then always end up in the successful path on the client (where it can check the error code of course).

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Do you mean the standard return type of a method or the parameter that gets back to your client?

Comment: It works both ways, it is a matter of preference. Right now, I don't see another way of returning a value from a server method.

Answer (score 0):

What about

`HubException`  in
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`.

This is available in ASP.NET Core.
This exception is thrown on the server and sent to client. You can also derive from that class to put your own information in it.